# Startup a Ubuntu FTP and SSH server without logging in

Tags: server, ssh, login, headless, sftp

I have a Ubuntu Server 11.10 box, which I would like to run "headless", and without a keyboard, mouse or display. Is it possible that immediately after startup the machine logs into an account, or allows me to control the machine from my Windows 7 machine nearby via SSH and SFTP?

1. I've got OpenSSH server installed, and even when the box is not logged in I can start an SSH session.
2. I've tried installing VSFTPD but its very troublesome (hardly connects) and only starts when I login locally into the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSH and other services should start-up without requiring any user to login. OpenSSH also provides SFTP (and SCP) capability; you don't need any dedicated SFTP daemon. Essentially, install OpenSSH (and remove VSFTPD, unless you specifically want FTP), and you should be able to log into a shell and transfer files over SFTP just fine on a headless box.

Answer (score 1):

Upstart should be able to handle that. Just start sshd at startup.

Here are a couple of good references:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1895084

Tim